# Bash - How to run function when the terminal is resized?

Tags: bash

How I can run the `fce_exitus` when the terminal is resized?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: What is `fce_exitus`?

Comment: This is my define function is system

Comment: It really does not matter. To people who know the answer the question is clear.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `PROMPT_COMMAND`. Put the following into your `.bashrc` file:

```
check_terminal_size () {
    if [[ "$LINES $COLUMNS" != "$previous_lines $previous_columns" ]]; then
        fce_exitus
    fi
    previous_lines=$LINES
    previous_columns=$COLUMNS
}

PROMPT_COMMAND="check_terminal_size; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Since `bash` updates `LINES` and `COLUMNS` when it receives `SIGWINCH`, you could also trap that signal instead of using `PROMPT_COMMAND`. However, your shell may receive `SIGWINCH` several times during a single terminal resize if you are, for example, resizing by dragging the window frame. So an alternative to setting `PROMPT_COMMAND` would be

```
trap 'check_terminal_size' WINCH
```

Comment: Thank you, but are empty variables $LINES and $COLUMNS? Why? thank you

Comment: `LINES` and `COLUMNS` should be set automatically by `bash`. I have no explanation if they are not.

Comment: I'd think PROMPT_COMMAND is only run just before bash shows a new prompt - that would mean you only get an update after you perform some action in the shell. Your second suggestion using trap will provide continuous updates even if you don't perform actions on the command-line yourself - thats probably better.